# PHP Insert multi-dimensional array into another multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this two arrays:

```
Array
(
    [InterfacedaRequisicaodePagamento] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SequenciadoRegistro] => 15015
                    [CodigodaContadoDocumento] =>  
                )

        )

)
```

and

```
Array
(
    [InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CodigodoProjeto] =>  
                )

        )

)
```

What I need is to insert the second array after the `CodigodaContadoDocumento` item of the first array to make a JSON string, but `array_push` don't work for it, and I don't know how to use `array_splice` in this case.

I'm using

```
array_push($interfaceRequisicaoPagamento, $interfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento);
```

and the result is the following:

```
    Array (
    [InterfacedaRequisicaodePagamento] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [SequenciadoRegistro] => 15015
            [CodigodaContadoDocumento] => 
        )
    )
    [0] => Array (
        [InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [CodigodoProjeto] => 
            )
        )
    )
)
```

But what I need is:

```
Array
(
    [InterfacedaRequisicaodePagamento] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [SequenciadoRegistro] => 15015
                [CodigodaContadoDocumento] =>  
                [InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CodigodoProjeto] =>  
                        )

                )
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you post your code? `array_push()` should work just fine.

Comment: Please, add the expected outcome to your question. (Why don't people post copy-able arrays? xD)

Comment: @jeroen I'm using `array_push($interfaceRequisicaoPagamento, $interfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento);`, and the result is the following:

 Array
 (
  [InterfacedaRequisicaodePagamento] => Array
   (
    [0] => Array
     (
      [SequenciadoRegistro] => 15015
      [CodigodaContadoDocumento] =>  
     )

   )

  [0] => Array
   (
    [InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento] => Array
     (
      [0] => Array
       (
        [CodigodoProjeto] =>  
       )

     )

   )

 )

Comment: Info added to the question. And what is the expected result?

Comment: @FirstOne The expected result is:

 Array
 (
  [InterfacedaRequisicaodePagamento] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SequenciadoRegistro] => 15015
                    [CodigodaContadoDocumento] =>  
     [InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento] => Array
     (
      [0] => Array
       (
        [CodigodoProjeto] =>  
       )

     )
                )
        )
 )

Answer (score 3):

Try it.

```
<?php 

$array1 = array('InterfacedaRequisicaodePagamento' => array
            ( 0 => array
                (
                    'SequenciadoRegistro' => 15015,
                    'CodigodaContadoDocumento' =>  ''
                ) ) );
$array2  = array('InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento' => array
        (0 => array
            (
                'CodigodoProjeto' =>  ''
            )));
$array1['InterfacedaRequisicaodePagamento']['0']['InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento'] = $array2['InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);
$jsonData = json_encode($array1);
echo $jsonData;

?>
```

=> OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [InterfacedaRequisicaodePagamento] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SequenciadoRegistro] => 15015
                    [CodigodaContadoDocumento] => 
                    [InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [CodigodoProjeto] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
{"InterfacedaRequisicaodePagamento":[{"SequenciadoRegistro":15015,"CodigodaContadoDocumento":"","InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento":[{"CodigodoProjeto":""}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

That can work as well:

```
<?php
$array1 = array('InterfacedaRequisicaodePagamento' => array(array('SequenciadoRegistro' => 15015, 'CodigodaContadoDocumento' => null)));
$array2 = array('InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento' => array(array('CodigodoProjeto' => null)));

print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);

$array1['InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento'] = $array2['InterfaceGrupoRequisicaodePagamento'];

print_r($array1);
```